# Can 32-bit Anaconda install 64-bit Spyder?

Tags: spyder

I have installed Anaconda 4.4.0 (32-bit) and Python 2.7.13(bit), however, I need to use 64-bit Spyder, so I want to know whether can I install 64-bit Spyder in 32-bit Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, it's not possible.